# Subtracting dates with Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time, subtraction

I'm just having a look at ruby and was playing with the date/time thing.

```
irb(main):001:0> jamis_DOB = Time.mktime(2003, 10, 22, 06, 59)
=> Wed Oct 22 06:59:00 +0300 2003
irb(main):002:0> age = Time.now - jamis_DOB
=> 222934108.172989
irb(main):005:0> age_in_years = (((age / 3600) / 24) / 365).to_i
=> 7
```

So my example is not so good as age_in_years won't know if there are leap years as those years add up. 
I've been through some googled time/date tutorials and haven't found an easy way to just subtract two dates and have it return in a years, months, days etc... format.
I'm guessing ruby has an add-on or something built-in for this kind of thing. Could someone tell me what it is? (Also, any advice how to find the answers to this type of thing for future reference?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want [`Date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) instead of [`Time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html):

```
require 'date'

now = Date.today
before = Date.civil(2000, 1, 1)
difference_in_days = (now - before).to_i

(difference_in_days/365.25).to_i
```

Will give you the difference in years between today and January 1st 2000. It can probably be improved, I just used the average number of days per year (365.25), which will give you the right answer except in extreme edge cases.

You can also do something like this:

```
require 'date'

years = 0
d = Date.civil(2000, 1, 1)
loop do
  d = d.next_year
  break if Date.today < d
  years += 1
end
```

But `Date#next_year` was introduced in Ruby 1.9, so it wouldn't work in 1.8.7.

Of course, the easiest way of determining the number of years between two dates is just subtracting the numbers:

```
2010 - 2000 # => 10
```

Comment: Thanks Theo :)
Your 3rd suggestion inspired me to do...

require 'date'

date_now = Date.today 
dob = Date.civil(2003, 10, 22) 

if date_now.month > dob.month
    age = date_now.year - dob.year
    elsif date_now.month == dob.month && date_now.day > dob.day
        age = date_now.year - dob.year
        
    else
        age = (date_now.year - dob.year) - 1 
    end
end

print "Correct age is: ", age, "\n"

I couldn't really understand your second suggestion yet and can't seem to get 1.9 running to play with it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the last example has to take the month and day into account too, of course. The middle example just steps one year for each turn in the loop and counts the turns. I've changed it to be a little more correct.

Comment: I was getting quite confused about why Ruby was always returning a `/1` after my date subtractions, was important to do a `to_i` on the result as mentioned above to get the value as a number of days.