# Get time when subtracting two times?

Tags: ruby

When subtracting two times a float is returned:

```
result = Time.now - user.last_logged_in #float
```

I need a time object, and not a float, for the [IMAP `format_date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-c-format_date) method.  Is this possible?

Comment: What time should it be? For example: today, 12:00 - today, 10:00 = ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177102/subtracting-dates-with-ruby

Comment: Maybe this: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date/Delta.html

Comment: I think I can use seconds ago?  (Time.now - user.last_logged_in).seconds.ago

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a date from an other and expecting the returned value to be a date, does not make much sense: If you subtract Januar, 1st 2013 from today what do you expect to be the result? What do you think would be the year of the Time object you expect?

I guess you want to know the delta between the two time objects. And that delta can be small (seconds) or big (years). Therefore Ruby returns the number of seconds between both dates. It is up to you to transfer the result in something more readable.

Perhaps you want to take a look how implementation of `distance_of_time_in_words` looks in Rails (older version from Rails 2.3.14, newer versions are more verbose):

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb, line 63
def distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time = 0, include_seconds = false, options = {})
  from_time = from_time.to_time if from_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
  to_time = to_time.to_time if to_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
  distance_in_minutes = (((to_time - from_time).abs)/60).round
  distance_in_seconds = ((to_time - from_time).abs).round

  I18n.with_options :locale => options[:locale], :scope => :'datetime.distance_in_words' do |locale|
    case distance_in_minutes
      when 0..1
        return distance_in_minutes == 0 ?
               locale.t(:less_than_x_minutes, :count => 1) :
               locale.t(:x_minutes, :count => distance_in_minutes) unless include_seconds

        case distance_in_seconds
          when 0..4   then locale.t :less_than_x_seconds, :count => 5
          when 5..9   then locale.t :less_than_x_seconds, :count => 10
          when 10..19 then locale.t :less_than_x_seconds, :count => 20
          when 20..39 then locale.t :half_a_minute
          when 40..59 then locale.t :less_than_x_minutes, :count => 1
          else             locale.t :x_minutes,           :count => 1
        end

      when 2..44           then locale.t :x_minutes,      :count => distance_in_minutes
      when 45..89          then locale.t :about_x_hours,  :count => 1
      when 90..1439        then locale.t :about_x_hours,  :count => (distance_in_minutes.to_f / 60.0).round
      when 1440..2529      then locale.t :x_days,         :count => 1
      when 2530..43199     then locale.t :x_days,         :count => (distance_in_minutes.to_f / 1440.0).round
      when 43200..86399    then locale.t :about_x_months, :count => 1
      when 86400..525599   then locale.t :x_months,       :count => (distance_in_minutes.to_f / 43200.0).round
      else
        distance_in_years           = distance_in_minutes / 525600
        minute_offset_for_leap_year = (distance_in_years / 4) * 1440
        remainder                   = ((distance_in_minutes - minute_offset_for_leap_year) % 525600)
        if remainder < 131400
          locale.t(:about_x_years,  :count => distance_in_years)
        elsif remainder < 394200
          locale.t(:over_x_years,   :count => distance_in_years)
        else
          locale.t(:almost_x_years, :count => distance_in_years + 1)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Subtracting a date from another date makes a lot of sense when you want to know the delta between the two.

Comment: @theTinMan : You are right. But it does not make sense the expect the returned value to be a date.

Comment: Correct, assuming a Date, DateTime or Time result would be wrong. Ruby needs a TimeInterval class that can be applied to each of those other classes equally.