# Get the difference in days between two dates Rails "Date"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

What is the proper way to subtract or add dates in Rails?

I tried the intuitive way but got Rational:

> irb(main):089:0> Date.today.increase_by("3 days")
>
> => Sun, 19 May 2019
>
> irb(main):090:0> Date.today
>
> => Thu, 16 May 2019
>
> irb(main):091:0> Date.today.increase_by("3 days") - Date.today
>
> => (3/1)

Disclaimer: Please note that I am new to Ruby and Rails as well. 2 months of experience so far :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting dates with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177102/subtracting-dates-with-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Date.today # Thu, 16 May 2019

Date.today + 3 # Thu, 19 May 2019

Date.today - 3 # Thu, 13 May 2019
```

For Difference

```
Date.today + 3 # Thu, 19 May 2019

Date.today - 3 # Thu, 13 May 2019

(d1 - d2).to_i # 6 (Days)
```

Comment: What you have shown is operation between Date and integer not between two dates.

Comment: The answer is updated. By doing `.to_i` you can find the number of days between two dates

Comment: Got it ? @Hairi